# Does Dasblog or Blogengine.net support posting via email?

Tags: email, blogengine.net

I have been unable to determine for sure if DasBlog or Blogengine.net support the ability to create blog posts via email?  Please let me know if you know for sure if this functionality is possible and preferably a resource about it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think either support posts via email.

You could put in a feature request:

http://blogengine.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=9041

Comment: Blogengine already has the feature listed for future implementation.  http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/page/Feature-table.aspx

Comment: hanks that is an outdated feature list, though it does appear they have not added the functionality in 1.6 or just released 2.0

Comment: I have created a free web application to do this at blogbyemail.com

Comment: @Brettski - is the source available somewhere? I would like to host it internally

Comment: @mcintyre321 Not currently, but to set up for a single blog is fairly simple.  The goal of the site is to support multiple blogging engines.  It uses Cooks Computing XMLRPC library (xml-rpc.net) for posting